# ExtJS: add button to htmleditor

Tags: extjs, html-editor

I am using ExtJS and I have a htmleditor in my form. I would like to add a custom button to that element (for example after all other buttons like alignments, font weights, ...). This button should basically insert a standard template in the htmlfield. Being this template html, the behaviour of the button should be like this

- Switch to HTML mode (like when pressing Source button)
- Insert something
- Switch back to WYSIWYG mode (like when pressing the Source button again)

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to switch to HTML mode. Just use the `insertAtCursor` function with the HTML template.

I made this easy example of how to add button which inserts a horizontal ruler (`<hr>` tag):

```
Ext.ns('Ext.ux.form.HtmlEditor');

Ext.ux.form.HtmlEditor.HR = Ext.extend(Ext.util.Observable, {
    init: function(cmp){
        this.cmp = cmp;
        this.cmp.on('render', this.onRender, this);
    },
    onRender: function(){
        this.cmp.getToolbar().addButton([{
            iconCls: 'x-edit-bold', //your iconCls here
            handler: function(){
                this.cmp.insertAtCursor('<hr>');
            },
            scope: this,
            tooltip: 'horizontal ruler',
            overflowText: 'horizontal ruler'
        }]);
    }
});
Ext.preg('ux-htmleditor-hr', Ext.ux.form.HtmlEditor.HR);

Ext.QuickTips.init();
new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'htmleditor',
        plugins: [new Ext.ux.form.HtmlEditor.HR()]
    }]
});
```

You can see it running at: [jsfiddle.net/protron/DCGRg/183/](http://jsfiddle.net/protron/DCGRg/183/embedded/result,js,resources/)

But I really recommend you to check out **[HtmlEditor.Plugins](https://github.com/VinylFox/ExtJS.ux.HtmlEditor.Plugins)** (or **[ateodorescu/mzExt](https://github.com/ateodorescu/mzExt/#extuxformpluginhtmleditor)** for ExtJS 4). There you can find a lot more about adding custom buttons, for instance, how to enable/disable the buttons when something is selected, put separators, etc.

Comment: .addButton([{ .. }]) - is not working -
instead, you should use: 
this.cmp.getToolbar().add({  /* buttons definitions */})

Comment: @snir Thanks! `add` is needed since ExtJS v4 ([sample v4](http://jsfiddle.net/protron/DCGRg/186/)). `addButton` works fine in ExtJS v3 ([sample v3](http://jsfiddle.net/protron/DCGRg/187/)).

Answer (score 1):

You also can use ExtJS.ux.HtmlEditor.Plugins : https://github.com/VinylFox/ExtJS.ux.HtmlEditor.Plugins

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@proton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146513/protron) great answer above, there's another way to **insert** buttons to the toolbar, different from adding them to the end.
In my answer i'll write it as a new control named 'RichTextBox' (and not as a plugin) but this can be done in any other way:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.RichTextBox', {
 extend: 'Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor',
  xtype: 'richtextbox',
  enableSourceEdit: false, // i choose to hide the option that shows html
  initComponent: function () {
     this.on('render', this.onRender, this);
     this.callParent();
  },
  /**
  * Insert buttons listed below to the html-editor at specific position.
  * handler is implemented using 'execCommand':
  * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand
  */
  onRender: function () {
    var me = this;
    var tb = me.getToolbar();
    var btns = {
       StrikeThrough: {
          //xtype: 'button', // button is default item for this toolbar
          itemId: 'btnStrikeThrough',
          iconCls: 'x-toolbar-strikethrough ', //choose icon with css class
          enableOnSelection: true,
          overflowText: 'StrikeThrough',
          tooltip: {
              title: 'StrikeThrough',
              text: 'Toggles strikethrough on/off for the selection or at the insertion point'
          },
          handler: function () {
              this.getDoc().execCommand('strikeThrough', false, null);
          },
          scope: this,
        },
        /** Seperator */
        sep: "-"
    };
    tb.insert(5, btns.StrikeThrough); // insert button to the toolbar
    //tb.insert(10, btns.sep); // add seperator
    //tb.remove(26); // remove button, seperator, etc.

    this.callParent(); //important: call regular 'onRender' here or at the start of the foo
  }
});
```