# Add buttons to HTML editor in extJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have used htmleditor in extJs but there is no option of editing text written inside the box. So i created buttons on my own and placed just inside the text editor but its not looking good.

Is there any way by which we can add buttons (2 buttons in same row) to html text editor.
To be short I want to add "Save" and "Cancel" button below inside html editor.

How can i do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900269/extjs-add-button-to-htmleditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [ExtJS.ux.HtmlEditor.Plugins](https://github.com/VinylFox/ExtJS.ux.HtmlEditor.Plugins) - (Set of Plugins for extended ExtJS HtmlEditor functionality ) for creating your own button. one thing you should do is that extending *Ext.ux.form.HtmlEditor.MidasCommand* in plugin...then adding this to your js file:

```
Ext.ux.form.HtmlEditor.Save= Ext.extend(Ext.ux.form.HtmlEditor.MidasCommand, {
    midasBtns: ['|',{
        cmd: 'save',
        title: 'Save'
    }]
});
```

and for button icons you can use this style:

```
.x-save {background: url(../images/save.png) 0 0 no-repeat !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ExtJS.ux.HtmlEditor.Plugins

[image]

https://github.com/VinylFox/ExtJS.ux.HtmlEditor.Plugins